# Properties of conjugate function of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-functions, several-complex-variables

I know that if $f(z)$ is an analytic function then $\ln|f(z)|$ is a harmonic function. I have tried to prove it but I have not found. Who can show me how to do?

Comment: Maybe use ${1 \over 2} \ln |f(z)|^2$? Also, you need $f(z) \ne 0$.

Comment: I knew that and I did, but it appeared $\dfrac{\partial^2{\overline{f}}}{\partial{\overline{z}}^2}$, I can prove $\dfrac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial z}=0$  or $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=0$, but I have not proved $\dfrac{\partial^2{\overline{f}}}{\partial{\overline{z}}^2}=0$.

Comment: We can prove that $f(z)$ analytic if and only if $\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=0$, $\dfrac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial z}=0\Leftrightarrow\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}=0$ when $f(z)$ analytic, and ${\overline{\left(\dfrac{\partial{\overline{f}}}{\partial{\overline{z}}}\right)}}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

Comment: locally around any point where $f(z) \ne 0$ we can define a holomorphic $\log f$ and $\log |f|=\Re \log f$ is harmonic; but using the laplacian condition we notice that harmonicity is a local property, so a function that is harmonic around any point in an open set, it is harmonic on the open set...